# Implementation of circular linked list using C++

Tags: c++, list, stl, linked-list

I am trying to implement circular linked list using list STL in C++.

I completed the circular linked list,but, there were some points that I didn't get. Therefore I post the problem in this page.

Below is my code showing the circular linked list.

```
list<int> survivors;


for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    survivors.push_back(i);
}


list<int>::iterator kill = survivors.begin();

int cnt = 0;

while (1) {
    kill = survivors.erase(kill);

    if (kill == survivors.end()) kill = survivors.begin();
```

As you can, I pushed the values into the list and then the procedure is going to the while loop.
In the while loop, I removed the values using iterator and if the current iterator reaches to the end, then I reassign the current iterator as the front position ( this codes makes the list working as the circular linked list).

Anyway, my problems is the following codes.

```
list<int> survivors;


for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    survivors.push_back(i);
}


list<int>::iterator kill = survivors.begin();

int cnt = 0;

while (1) {
    kill = survivors.erase(kill);

    for (int i = 0; i < k - 1; i++) {
        if (kill == survivors.end()) {
            kill = survivors.begin();
        }
        else {
            kill++;
        }
    }
```

Second one is totally same codes except for the last part. I changed a little bit by inserting for loop and if section.

However, my problem is that the "kill= survivors.begin();" were not called even though iterator reached to the end of the list.

I tried again and again and print out but I didn't know why the procedure couldn't go into the inside of the if section even though iterator "kill" reached to the end of list.

Therefore, I tried to print out the end element of the list as shown below.

```
cout <<*survivors.end()<<endl;
```

it returns error message saying that I tried to reference the unknown value.

Since I am not very much familiar with C++ STL, so could anybody fix my problems?

Comment: Your loop condition is the main problem.
Also, you can't dereference an `end` iterator (it's not the last element, it's usually one beyond the end of the container, so trying to read from it invokes undefined behaviour)

Comment: Please post the minimal (complete) code that reproduces the problem - I can't see where `k` is initialised, for a start. Is your list `std::list`, or a container you wrote yourself? What is the actual error message, and is it a compile error, or a runtime exception, or something else?

Comment: @OMGtechy Could you explain the problem invoked by loop condition? I didnt know why

Comment: Useless ok i will post as you indicatef

Comment: I agree with @OMGtechy , you should check the value of **`k`** to see if the loop run as your expectation.

Comment: if `k==n` you exit from the first iteration of `for` with `kill == survivors.end()`; then `survivors.erase(kill)` is `survivors.erase(survivors.end())` can crash the program